# MATLAB ttest example not working

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run the code from MATLAB website for t-Test.

```
load stockreturns;
x = stocks(:,3);
[h,p,ci,stats] = ttest(x)
```

But the error I get is:

```
??? Error using ==> nanstd
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> ttest at 105
sdpop = nanstd(x,[],dim);
```

The above should be a working example as it is from the [ttest documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest.html#btqtp5q-2).

Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong here? I did print the variable `x` in the code above and it is not having any NaNs, etc.

I am using Matlab 2010.

Comment: What does `which nanstd` say?

Comment: i:\ja\prod\matlab\utilities\stats\nanstd.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not MATLAB's `nanstd`. Try `which -all nanstd` to see where all versions of that function are.  One of them should be the correct `nanstd.m`.  To fix the problem, do one of:

1. Remove the offending `nanstd.m` from your path.
2. Move the path down in priority below MATLAB's version (in `toolbox\stats\stats`).

Comment: How do I achieve the (2) Move the path down in priority below MATLAB's version (in toolbox\stats\stats).

Comment: `pathtool`.  Select and move to bottom.  Can you post `which -all nanstd` for reference?